# Symfony - uploading images and saving as blob

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm using SF1.4 and Propel and I'm having a slight problem with trying to save images to a field in my database.

Does anyone have a small example that I could work from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a bad experience saving images as blobs. Specially when you have to change your database engine. But if you still want to go that way. I found this useful http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/t/25699/ though its based on Doctrine.

Answer (score 5):

Keep your images in a filesystem. Is there a special reason to store images in a db ? 
You can store only generated filename. Because storing blobs in mysql will freeze your application. Give this task to a webserver.

Comment: Yes. Symfony provides functionality for this as well.

Comment: There is no special reason as such, I'd like to store them in the database rather than the filesystem